# Why this mocking script doesn't work (unittest, Mocker, python)

Tags: python

I want to mock MyClass.toBeMockedMethod which is called in MyClass.mymethod using the following script. It runs without actually mocking it. Not sure why....

```
class Test_mytest(MockerTestCase): 

   def mock_it_up(self, function, result=None, mmin=0, mmax=None):
      function = self.m.mock()
      function(ARGS)
      self.m.result(result)
      self.m.count(mmin, mmax)

   def setUp(self):
      self.m = Mocker()

      self.mock_it_up(MyClass.toBeMockedMethod)

      self.o=Myclass(0)


   def test_one_atom(self):
      self.o.mymethod()


   def tearDown(self):
      pass

if __name__ == '__main__': 
   main()
```

Answer (score 0):

As with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349754/can-we-pass-a-function-and-the-mocker-to-another-function-for-mocking) what you're really trying to do is [patch](http://labix.org/mocker#head-83d80b643ee8544628ee7a8301a72443ac51a173) your instance of `MyClass`. If `MyClass` is a [new-style class](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes) then you can do this:

```
class Test_mytest(MockerTestCase):

    def mock_it_up(self, function, result = None, mmin = 0, mmax = None):
        methodToMock = getattr(self.p, function)
        methodToMock()
        self.m.result(result)
        self.m.count(mmin, mmax)

    def setUp(self):
        self.m = Mocker()
        self.o = MyClass(0)
        self.p = self.m.patch(self.o)
        self.mock_it_up('toBeMockedMethod')
        # Put more calls to mock_it_up here.
        self.m.replay()

    def test_one_atom(self):
        self.o.mymethod()
```

This will modify `self.o` so that calls to `toBeMockedMethod` are mocked.

However, if `MyClass` is not a new-style class then patching won't work. In this case, you can use [type simulation](http://labix.org/mocker#head-d5f3e7a31a406ee658f82807bed111545e3c4522) to trick `MyClass` into doing what you want. For example:

```
class Test_mytest(MockerTestCase):

    def mock_it_up(self, function, result = None, mmin = 0, mmax = None):
        methodToMock = getattr(self.mockObj, function)
        methodToMock()
        self.m.result(result)
        self.m.count(mmin, mmax)

    def setUp(self):
        self.m = Mocker()
        self.o = MyClass(0)
        self.mockObj = self.m.mock(MyClass)
        self.mock_it_up('toBeMockedMethod')
        # Put more calls to mock_it_up here.
        self.m.replay()

    def test_one_atom(self):
        MyClass.mymethod(self.mockObj)
```

Note that the mocker's `mock` method is called with the class to be type-simulated. Later, instead of calling `self.o.mymethod()` we call `MyClass.mymethod(...)`. Now `MyClass.mymethod()` expects an instance of `MyClass` as its first argument, but fortunately the mock object is masquerading as an instance of `MyClass` so the call goes through. When `mymethod()` calls `toBeMockedMethod()` it will actually call the mocked method, not the real method.

I quickly hacked up an test `MyClass` like this:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def toBeMockedMethod(self):
        print "Not Mocked!"

    def mymethod(self):
        self.toBeMockedMethod()
```

and when I ran this code as a unit test I got:

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

OK
```

which is the desired result.

Comment: I'm trying your sample and I get "can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'instance'"  when I call to m.replay()

Comment: @ApriOri The code worked for me when I tested it back in December of 2011. You might like to ask a question on StackOverflow listing your code and asking for assistance.