# Can we pass a function and the mocker to another function for mocking?

Tags: python

I want to pass the function form along with the mocker to another function in the testing class, and expect the function will be mocked after returning. However, it seemed not working, and thanks for any suggestions!

```
class Cls():
   def submthd(self):
      return 0
   def mthd(self):
      a=self.submthd()
      return a

class Test_me(MockerTestCase):
   def setUp(self):
      pass

   def mockup(self,f,m):
      f = m.mock()
      f(ARGS)
      m.result(1)
      m.replay()

   def test_null(self):
      m=Mocker()
      o=Cls()
      self.mockup(o.submthd,m)
      self.assertEqual(o.mthd(),1)
      m.verify()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be mistaken, but it seems to me that what you're trying to do is called ["Patching"](http://labix.org/mocker#head-83d80b643ee8544628ee7a8301a72443ac51a173) in Python Mocker parlance. You want to change the behaviour of the `submthd()` call on the existing instance of `Cls()`.

Firstly, you need to use [new style classes](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes) (e.g. subclasses of `object`). So let's redefine `Cls()`:

```
class Cls(object):
    def submthd(self):
        return 0
    def mthd(self):
        return self.submthd()
    def submthd2(self):
        return 0
    def mthd2(self):
        return self.submthd()
```

I've added `submthd2` and `mthd2` to show how you can use your `mockup(...)` method on multiple methods, but otherwise your class is essentially unchanged.

Now, in order to use patching in your test case you would do something like this:

```
class Test_me(MockerTestCase):
    def mockup(self, p, f, m):
        methodToCall = getattr(p, f)
        methodToCall()
        m.result(1)

    def test_null(self):
        m = Mocker()
        o = Cls()
        p = m.patch(o)
        self.mockup(p, 'submthd', m)
        self.mockup(p, 'submthd2', m)
        m.replay()
        self.assertEqual(o.mthd(), 1)
        self.assertEqual(o.mthd2(), 1)
        m.verify()
```

When I run this code as a unit test I get:

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

OK
```

Comment: It really works, but I am not allowed to change the source code, so is there anyway I can get around this problem without making it a subclass of object?

Comment: See my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347573/why-this-mocking-script-doesnt-work-unittest-mocker-python) where I deal with the case where the class you're testing is not a subclass of object.